# Onedrive access and VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, sdk, live

i have Problems to convert the following code to vb.net . iam curently work with the live sdk 5.6 on wp8
are there some other samples that can i use with vb.net?

```
  private async void GetMe()
        {
            try
            {
                LiveOperationResult operationResult = await this.liveClient.GetAsync("me");

                dynamic properties = operationResult.Result;
                this.tbResponse.Text = properties.first_name + " " + properties.last_name;
            }
            catch (LiveConnectException e)
            {
                this.tbResponse.Text = e.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work (used [telerik converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)):

```
Private Sub GetMe()
    Try
        Dim operationResult As LiveOperationResult = Await Me.liveClient.GetAsync("me")    
        Dim properties As dynamic = operationResult.Result
        Me.tbResponse.Text = properties.first_name + " " + properties.last_name
    Catch e As LiveConnectException
        Me.tbResponse.Text = e.ToString()
    End Try
End Sub
```